# Background-image not appearing

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm new to HTML and CSS in general. Please help me with the code. I cannot get the background-image to appear in my browser although i typed the syntax correctly. All i get is an orange box, with no alert.png image. I'm following an online tutorial btw: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/31-css-background-images/#thecode

Edit 1: The image, html file and css file are all inside the same folder. Yet no success.

Edit 2: I used an unique css file name instead of a generic "style.css" (which i have several of them in my system) and it worked! Make sure there's no space between url and the parenthesis.

HTMl code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
        charset=utf-8">
        <title>alert message</title>
    </head>

    <body>
<p class="alert">
  <strong>Alert!</strong> 
    This is an alert message.
</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.alert {
width: 20em;
background-image: url(C:\Documents and Settings\USER\My Documents\alert.png);
background-color:orange;
margin: auto;
padding: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Your code works as it is. Make sure the image is where you expect it to be. Check that it is accessible and permissions are not an issue. See: http://jsfiddle.net/UWFcL/

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by permissions? I placed the image in the same folder as the html file yet i can't get it to work.

Comment: if its in the same folder as the html file, permissions shouldn't be a problem. Try using quotes as mentioned by Ramon

Answer (score 2):

The url must be a string:

```
url("C:\Documents and Settings\USER\My Documents\alert.png");
```

Comment: Your url doesn't have "spaces" so it works without being a string. His url has a space here: \My Documents\ so it must be a string.

Comment: I tried using url(full pathway) using strings but still to no avail.

Comment: Maybe you'll need to escape the backslashes, try `url("C:\\Documents and Settings\\USER\\My Documents\\alert.png");`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's a permissions issue, regardless you will most likely have problems with the URL being a file reference when you move this to a server, I would recommend moving your image into the same location (or better yet an image folder in the root of your site) as your html file and then modify your css to be this

```
.alert {
  width: 20em;
  background-image: url('/alert.png'); /* '/images/alert.png' */
  background-color:orange;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

Comment: I added it in an 'images' folder and placed it inside the same folder as html and css files. Yet can't get it to work using url('alert.png')/url('/images/alert.png')

Comment: I think you have a permissions issue then. Are you running this on a local web server or hosted environment?

Comment: I'm not running any server that i know of. I'm just creating html and css files and running the html files using firefox.

Comment: so your not running your html pages under IIS or apache or anything like that?  Then that might be why it's not working this way.  In order to render HTML pages using css and in the fashion you want to you will need to put the files under your Default Web Site in IIS (if your running windows).  Or create a new site for them under there.  This might get you started: http://www.plus2net.com/asp-tutorial/iis-localsite.php If that doesn't help then I'd suggest doing some googling as to how to setup a website locally.

Comment: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/196/webproblem.png/) here's the picture of the local web server i set up. It still doesn't work. I have no idea what i've been doing wrong here...

Comment: Ah! I made it work! The "style.css" file name is too common, i have several "style.css" littered throughout my computer when i create sample webpages. Instead i used an unique name for the css file and it worked! I tried setting the local host directory to random folders and it still worked. So permission is not a issue. Thanks for the help though. But i still got a question. If i can get it working without setting a specific local host directory, what is its use then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "If i can get it working without setting a specific local host directory, what is its use then?" Are you just running it from a location on your hard drive and not the home directory where IIS is pointing?

Comment: Yeah anywhere on my hard drive, not necessarily where IIS is pointing, and that works. So i don't understand why i need to use IIS as a pointer.

Comment: I guess technically you don't when working locally but if you wanted someone to hit your site from another machine you would need to set it up under iis.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing things is to put your text into a div, and set the image as the div's background image using css, like so:

```
<div class="alert">
   <p>
     <strong>Alert!</strong>
     This is an alert message.
   </p>
</div>
```

And, for the CSS:

```
.alert {
     width: 20em; (Width of entire div, which includes text and bg image)
     background-image: url('../alert.png');
     background-color: orange;
     margin: auto;
     padding: 2em;
}
```

You can see the live JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cwca22/TdDJY/

Also, in the code above, the background image will tile (repeat) both horizontally and vertically to fill the space of the div. In order to prevent this, you could make the div the same height and width as your background image, or put `background-repeat: no-repeat` in your css under the `.alert` class.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: I followed your code with the div format. But still no success.

Comment: The code appears to be working fine for me - do you have the address of your image right? If you have your site based in a folder called "Foo", and you are trying to reference an image in that folder, you could always use the <img src="../[image-name]"> format. The "../" means "start at the root folder of the site, then navigate to the file" instead of just "navigate to the file".

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL, if possible you can use firebug which is addon of firefox, which will definitely help you, by indicating if image has been loaded or not.

Else another solution would be give height to your alert class as follows

```
.alert {
  width: 20em;
  background-image: url('/alert.png'); /* '/images/alert.png' */
  background-color:orange;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2em;
  height: /* height of image*/
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me..I mean have you check if path of image is correct or not. Have you tried firebug to check if image has been loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

First put your alert.png picture in the same folder as your html file.

Then try this in your CSS file:

```
body {
     background: orange url("alert.png") no-repeat;
}
```

I think the problem was the "\" in \alert.png

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the original question he had in his css

> background-image: url(C:\Documents and Settings\USER\My Documents\alert.png);

I ran into problems with a gallery page that had images as background thumbnails.  Any image filename that had spaces would not appear. It was only the fact that one image happened to have underscores in place of spaces and that did appear that I was able to track it down.  As there are spaces in his url, this could be the problem.  I fixed my problem by using \ to escape any characters like spaces causing the problem. i.e.

> A\ space\ in\ the\ filename.jpg

though this might not work in a Windows pathname!
If the image is in the same directory as the script he shouldn't need the full url anyway.